# Why does unpacking this map object print "must be an iterable, not map"?

Tags: python, python-3.6

What is going on here?

```
>>> list(map(lambda *x: x, *map(None, 'abc')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
    list(map(lambda *x: x, *map(None, 'abc')))
TypeError: type object argument after * must be an iterable, not map
```

**Ignore the senselessness of the code.** This is about the error message, *"iterable, not map"*. Maps *are* iterables, are they not?

And if I only replace `None` with `str`, the whole thing works fine:

```
>>> list(map(lambda *x: x, *map(str, 'abc')))
[('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

So now Python doesn't have any issue with a `map` there after all.

This happens in my Python 3.6.1. My Python 3.5.2 instead raises the expected `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. And googling ["must be an iterable, not map"](https://www.google.com/search?q="must+be+an+iterable%2C+not+map") finds no results at all. So apparently this is something introduced just recently.

Is this just a Python bug? Or is there some sense to this?

**Update:** [Reported as bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue31071) now, as suggested.

Comment: `"My Python 3.5.2 instead raises the expected TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"` That's odd. On my Python 3.4.4 I get (almost) the same error as you do on 3.6: `TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not map`

Comment: Interesting. I just did `m = map(None, 'abc')` and then attempted to do `def f(*args): print(args); f(*m)` and Python raised a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.

Comment: Message was updated in the commit: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/7344285c1919e5ade8016a83a3ee02fd637a030d

Comment: The reason that doesn't trigger it is it goes through a different opcode `CALL_FUNCTION_EX` instead of `BUILD_TUPLE_UNPACK_WITH_CALL`

Comment: @DeepSpace That at least makes sense, since maps aren't sequences.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd consider this to be a bug.  Here's the source that causes this exception:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b1660800f4f519dbfab9e5a4ad3eae1cfabab3ed/Python/ceval.c#L2514-L2523

A disassembly of the python bytecode confirms it is using `BUILD_TUPLE_UNPACK_WITH_CALL`

The "bug" in the code above is it assumes *any* `TypeError` while `_PyList_Extend`ing the argument array means it wasn't an iterable, however `__iter__` itself could raise a TypeError.  It is rethrowing this exception

I'd suggest opening a bug at https://bugs.python.org

Comment: I can't fully comprehend Python's C sources, but I think you're right. I'll report it tomorrow (not starting that at 3:34 am :-)