# TypeError: type object argument after * must be an iterable, not itertools.map

Tags: python, pandas

I get the title error when I try to merge two dataframes on the left on the Name column. Here is the DataFrame.info() call on the two data frames.

```
Int64Index: 145 entries, 1 to 162 
Data columns (total 13 columns):
Quarter     145 non-null float64
Time        145 non-null object
Down        145 non-null float64
ToGo        145 non-null float64
Location    145 non-null object
Detail      145 non-null object
SEA         145 non-null float64
TAM         145 non-null float64
EPB         145 non-null float64
EPA         145 non-null float64
Win%        145 non-null float64
Name        145 non-null object
Yards       145 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(8), int64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 15.9+ KB
None

Int64Index: 1567 entries, 0 to 1566
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Name        1567 non-null object
Team        1567 non-null object
Position    1150 non-null object
Age         1567 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 61.2+ KB
None
```

And also the full traceback of the python stack.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weighted_random_forest.py", line 478, in <module>
    main()
  File "weighted_random_forest.py", line 473, in main
    game = get_third_down_conversion_rate(team, game, files)
  File "weighted_random_forest.py", line 339, in get_third_down_conversion_rate
    df = df.merge(roster, on='Name', how='left')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5370, in merge
    copy=copy, indicator=indicator, validate=validate)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 58, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 582, in get_result
    join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 748, in _get_join_info
    right_indexer) = self._get_join_indexers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 727, in _get_join_indexers
    how=self.how)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 1050, in _get_join_indexers
    llab, rlab, shape = map(list, zip(* map(fkeys, left_keys, right_keys)))
TypeError: type object argument after * must be an iterable, not itertools.imap
```

I managed to get the post mortem debugger to fire off to inspect the arguments to the variables going into the last call of map in pandas. However, I don't see any problems with the data. Is it perhaps because the two indexes are not numbered starting from 0 or 1? Do they both need indexes that start at the same offset?

I'm also a bit suspicious that perhaps map is being shadowed by itertools.imap so I excluded `import itertools` and instead used `from itertools import tee`. This, however, did not resolve the issue.

I also tried dropping NaN values from the tables before merging and this still failed. What can I do to try and fix this problem?

Braden.

**UPDATE**
I checked the value of left_keys: it contains a list([]) element for one of the cell values.

**UPDATE**

```
def name_matcher(Detail):
        res = re.findall('[A-Za-z\.\'\-]+ [A-Za-z\'\-]+', Detail)

        if len(res) != 0:
                return res[0]
        else:
                return []
```

And there you have it.

I cannot do that...

```
def name_matcher(Detail):
        res = re.findall('[A-Za-z\.\'\-]+ [A-Za-z\'\-]+', Detail)

        if len(res) != 0:
                return res[0]
        else:
                return ''
```

And that is the fix. I had an apply using these functions. The problem is now obvious as names that were empty would return an empty list instead of an empty string.

Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: IIRC, that exception happens if your `fkeys` throws an exception.

Comment: Ah, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363330/why-does-unpacking-this-map-object-print-must-be-an-iterable-not-map) the source I was remembering, and the [associated bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue31071). Check your `fkeys`, `left_keys`, and `right_keys`.

Comment: I'm not really sure what I am looking for. Also fkeys appears to be a partial and I have no clue what to do with that. Also the bug report you forwarded me too is for Python 3.*. This is Python 2.7. I dunno if that makes a difference or not...